# How to install Jupiter on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, jupiter, rpm

I have made some research how to install Jupiter on Ubuntu 14.04:

In therory:

- download the program (noarch.rpm) from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/files/)
- convert `.rpm` into `.deb`, by using `alien` program;
- add missing `jupiter` group to Ubuntu;
- install recently converted deb package;

In practic:

```
sudo apt-get install alien
sudo groupadd jupiter
cd ~/Downloads
sudo alien -k jupiter-0.1.11-1.noarch.rpm --scripts
sudo dpkg -i jupiter_0.1.11-1_all.deb
```

...in general, it works (it appears in `ps aux | grep jupiter` list), but there is still missing jupiter indicator. Someone knows how to get this done to work properly?

Comment: I disagree with the statement that this question has already been answered in the "Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?" topic. The author has explicitly asked for instruction HOW to INSTALL Jupiter and not if there are alternatives to it (though I find it very useful what @Rinzwind has stated at the very beginning of his answer about the current state of its development). Therefore the "This question already has an answer here" section should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development of Jupiter has [stopped](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/jupiter) as of 12.10.

> Someone knows how to get this done to work properly?

The RPM you used is the Redhat version and this will not have code specific to Ubuntu. Regarding the indicator: there is none, so if this is to continue someone needs to code an indicator for Jupiter.

Why the RPM? You would be better of [downloading](https://launchpad.net/~jolicloud-team/+archive/ppa) the Ubuntu version of Jupiter and use that (no need to mess with alien). This one does not have an indicator either though.

I would advice to take the more obvious road: forget about Jupiter and install TLP.